# How can I rank my Facebook friends by their friend count?

Tags: facebook

How can I rank my Facebook friends by their friend count?

I want to get a message out to a large variety of people and I'd like to see the top 10 friends of mine with the most friends.

Comment: This is interesting, I'd like to know how to do so also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done this, but from my research this is the best way to do it:

1. I need to use Facebook Query Language to get all my friends
2. I need to use a programming language (maybe javascript?) to loop over all my friends to get their friends, count them, and store the count in an array with the friend name.
3. I need to sort my array by the count.

Comment: You can do everything in the FQL query I think, you just need a way to join tables.

Comment: @phwd can you post the code for the join in an answer? That would really help me out.

Comment: Programming solutions aren't really in the scope of this site. It's better to ask on facebook.stackoverflow.com.